# Manually compile C code with command line to run on Android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, ndk-build

I want to compile some C code manually in order to run it on Android. The C code can be as simple as this hello world program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The result should be an executable binary file, which I can run with `adb` like this:

```
adb push exename /data/local/tmp
adb shell chmod 777 /data/local/tmp
adb shell /data/local/tmp
```

I am able to create such an executable with Android Studio and the NDK. To better understand the compiling process I want to know how I can manually compile the code with the command line. I know that there are different ABIs that are compiled with different tools, but the process should still be the same.

I am pretty sure it is possible as the NDK includes multiple executables like `aarch64-linux-android-as`, which allows me to compile Assembly to an executable. Unfortunately, I could not find any documentation of all tools included in the NDK in order to find out which is the correct tool myself.

The question now is if someone knows which tools of the NDK I have to use in order to create an executable from my provided C code. If the process for compiling multiple `.c` files into one binary is different from `gcc` I would also appreciate the process of compiling multiple files.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is there something that ends with `-gcc` or `-clang` like `aarch64-linux-android-clang`?

Comment: Thank you! Your comment led me to some other folder where multiple clang compilers are. They are called like this: `aarch64-linux-android30-clang`.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang --target=aarch64-linux-android21 helloworld.c -o helloworld`